# Import different tables from one db to another db

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I am new to database. I have a forum on one server. I would like to extract all data from this forum and then import to a different forum (with different table names and structure) on a different server.

My idea, which may be funny, is:

1) Export the forum db table records from the old server using phpMyAdmin.
2) Import the exported db to a temporary db.
3) Change the table and columns name and the structure to match the target forum db structure.
4) Re-export the table records from the temporary db.
5) Append the exported data to the target db to add the data to the new forum (in phpMyAdmin).

I know it might be inappropriate.

Is there an efficient process for this job? And are there any references which I can refer to? (I am currently searching information on importing/exporting database but I could not find useful resources yet...)

**Added**:
The old forum has a similar layout with bbPress. The final purpose is to import the data from the old forum to bbPress. The old forum has post title, post content, post date, post author, reply, reply content, reply author.. and so on. I would like to map them to the corresponding field in bbPress.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As long as the new forum software uses the same table structure and conventions (aside from the *name* differences you've mentioned), it sounds like your plan should work fine.

Comment: @Isaac. Thank you very much. If possible, can you please recommend me an appropriate book for this area in amazon?

Comment: Frankly I doubt such a resource exists. What you're trying to do -- take data from one application and massage it to work with another -- is limited in scope, specific to both tools, and unlikely to have a published book even mention details. You might be able to find a blog post referencing details.

Comment: @Isaac. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While SQL is somewhat standardized, databases and database operations are not so we need to know the specific databases you're working with. That said, most RDBMS databases have CLI tools to export one or more tables reasonably efficiently as well as CLI tools to import. Then it's a matter of translating possible incompatibilities of the output to what's needed for the input.

In general, the process is this:

1. export table data to SQL statements
2. if necessary, modify SQL statements to allow import
3. import modified SQL statements to new database
4. run table transformation (DDL) scripts on new database
5. append data in transformed table to existing table

For most RDBMS, you can also choose other export&import formats, like CSV. If you provide the details of both the databases, you'll get more specific help.

For example, for two MySQL databases, you can do the following:

```
    mysqldump -u username -p databaseName tableName > tableName.sql
```

Similarly, to import this data to a MySQL database:

```
    mysql -u username -p -D databaseName < tableName.sql
```

If the databases are compatible, then no transformations are needed (step 2).  To modify the newly imported table, you can do:

```
    mysql -u username -p -D databaseName < tableNameDDL.sql
```

**tableNameDDL.sql**:

```
    ALTER TABLE tableName ADD myNewColumn VARCHAR(60);
```

To append the data in `tableName` to your existing table, you can do:

```
    mysql -u username -p -D databaseName < tableNameAppend.sql
```

**tableNameAppend.sql**

```
    INSERT INTO existingTableName (c1, c2, c3 )
        SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM tableName;
```

You could do your transformations in the old database as well of course with an initial copy of the data into your temporary table prior to export.

Comment: Really thanks a lot for your prompt reply. Actually I have a forum with similar layout with bbPress. The final purpose is to import the data from the old forum to bbPress. The old forum has post title, post content, post date, post author, reply, reply content, reply author.. and so on. I would like to map them to the corresponding field in bbPress.

Comment: Could you please recommend any books which help me to understand this field? Thanks.

Comment: There are many good resources available including books and online. One excellent, and comprehensive, book is the [PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) which includes simple tutorials, as well as standard SQL sections.